# api key elastic aws not show

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the Elasticsearch service running on AWS in a VPC, and I need to know how to access its API from my machine.

"I tried to search for the policy, but I'm not sure which one would be suitable for this, or if additional configuration is needed in Cognito

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear (and rather short). Can you please Edit your question to provide more detail? For example, what do you mean by "the option for API key" and "I need to hit the API which uses Cognito"? It is unclear whether you are wanting to find something inside Elasticsearch or inside Cognito.

Comment: 1. you need to have access from your device to the Subnet where the OpenSearch cluster is, or you can launch an ec2 in the VPC to access the cluster
2. If during cluster creation you didn't add any credentials then OpenSearch will be accessible without credentials